# I had donated to UBUNTU but how do I get the latest UBUNTU software?

Tags: software-sources

How do I get the copy of UBUNTU after donating to UBUNTU?

Comment: Download it from Ubuntu.com

Answer (score 0):

If you already have Ubuntu installed then you can get the latest apps/softwares by

```
sudo apt-get install update
```

typing in the terminal(Ctrl+Alt+T)

If you don't have Ubuntu then follow the steps here to get LTS(Long term support) release of Ubuntu suitable for your needs and h/w by following this [link](http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop/install-ubuntu-desktop). I suggest Ubuntu Desktop 14.04.3 LTS

Answer (score 0):

After donating there was probably a link to download. If you missed it don't worry, you aren't required to donate.

If you go to the download link from the main website, there's a link on the bottom of the page "Not now, take me to the download ›"

But here are the direct links:

For 64 bit Desktop: 
http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop/thank-you/?version=14.04.3&architecture=amd64

For 32 bit Desktop: 
http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop/thank-you/?version=14.04.3&architecture=i386